# call an input again if the statements become false

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to ask user for the input unless **m = "1" or "2"** if 
 m becomes 1 it will call for fun1() again or if **m** becomes 2 it will exit the loop. if user give another value except 1 or 2 it ask for the value of **m** again.

```
def fun1():
    a = input("Which one do you want to log?\n"
              "1 for 'Jubayer\n"
              "2 for 'Anamul\n"
              "3 for 'Shrabon\n")
    return a


while True:
    person = fun1()
    if person in {"1", "2", "3"}:
        decision = di_ex()
        if decision == "1":
            diet(person)
        elif decision == "2":
            exercise(person)
        else:
            print("Try again.")
        m = input("Do you want to continue?\n"
                  "1 for Continue\n"
                  "2 for Exit\n")
        if m == "1":
            continue
        else:
            break

    else:
        print("You have failed."
              "Try again.")
```

Comment: Remove everything after `print("Try again.")`. It will work just fine.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque then it will not ask for continue or exit. if i give something else except 1 or 2 it will again ask for it:
```m = input("Do you want to continue?\n"
                  "1 for Continue\n"
                  "2 for Exit\n")```

Comment: @AhsanulHaque what if i give user an option either you want to continue the loop or not? what should i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another function for `Do you want...` prompt and put it inside while loop and break the loop if input is 1 or 2.

```
def fun2():

    while True:   
        m = input("Do you want to continue?\n"
             "1 for Continue\n"
             "2 for Exit\n")
        if m in ("1","2"):
            return m
```